# Very slow computer, after installing ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, performance

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my computer, and now it is impossible to use it because it runs very slow. I have an old Dell computer with an Intel Pentium R4 CPU clocked @ 2.80GHz. Can anyone help me?

Comment: How much RAM does your system have?

Comment: Free disk space would also be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `top` and see if you can reduce some of unused applications. Also a bug has been reported w.r.t to graphics `https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/1292467`

Answer (score 0):

That's a 10 year old single core CPU.  You're talking about Ubuntu with the Unity desktop?  That's designed for modern hardware.  It needs the same sort of power that Windows 7 or 8 does.

You read all kinds of stuff about Linux being great for old computers, and it is, but the part they don't tell you is that Linux technically is just the kernel.  That doesn't mean that the desktop ... or some app software ... will run properly on old hardware.

On old hardware you'd be better off doing a clean reinstall of Lubuntu 14.04.1.  Especially if there's less than 1GB of RAM.

Comment: Yes, Lubuntu or another alternative: Xubuntu.  Both those have less requirements for available resources.